# Elementary proof of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[Proof of Wilson's Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson's_Theorem)

In the elementary proof here, we solve by pairing an element with its inverse. Why do we know necessarily that this will always happen?

Comment: Hint. You know every element has an inverse. When can an element be its own inverse (remember your modulus is prime)?

Comment: when it is congruent to -1 or 1! thanks

Comment: You didn't read the article correctly. It explains that at length.

Answer (score 1):

Your real question is: how do we know we can pair each element with its own inverse?

The answer to this can be broken into a few pieces.

1. Every integer relatively prime to $p$ has an inverse mod $p$.
2. If $a$ has inverse $a^{-1}$ then $a^{-1}$ has inverse $a$.
3. What about elements which are their own inverse? This amounts to solving $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, whose only solutions are $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$.

And that's it. If there is a substep which you are not familiar with, then you might consider trying to prove it, or looking it up here or in your text.