# Proof that for any prime $p\geq 5$: $(p-1)!+1$ is not a prime

Tags: number-theory

Proof: for any prime $p\geq 5$, the number $(p-1)!+1$ is not a prime.

Could someone help me out please? I am looking for a proof to this theorem.

I have tried to prove it by multiplying $((p-1)!+1)$ with a number that is not a multiple of $p$ in order to obtain a multiple of $p$ (I think this would prove that it is a multiple of p).

**NOTE:** we have not learned anything about number theory yet, except the definition of a prime so I'm guessing the proof shouldn't use any nonintuitive results from number theory.

Comment: Yes, the complete question is in the title. Problem: the complete question should *always* be part of the body of the question.

Comment: "Could someone help me out please?" How do you suggest that we do so?

Comment: Isn't that obvious?

Comment: What's obvious:  You're currently supposed to be studying the section on Wilson's Theorem, and you blew off reading it, and homework is due tomorrow.

Comment: Read my comment to the answer below, we have not done anything on Wilsons theorem yet or any number theory.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to read comments on answers to understand the context of the question; you should include relevant facts in the question itself.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct! I have updated the question.

Comment: What emerged in the Comments discussing the answer posted by Dietrich Burde is that you want a proof that avoids modular arithmetic and indeed relies only on the definition of *prime number*.  This restriction (perhaps impossible to achieve) also deserves to be included in the body of your Question.

Answer (score 2):

By Wilson's theorem, which can be proved with elementary means,

[Elementary proof of Wilson's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658294/elementary-proof-of-wilsons-theorem)

we have
$$
p\mid (p-1)!+1,
$$
where $(p-1)!+1>p$ for all primes $p\ge 5$.

Comment: We have not discussed Wilsons Theorem

Comment: Then have a look at the elementary proof at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658294/elementary-proof-of-wilsons-theorem).

Comment: We would need $p\geq 5$ because for $p = 2, 3$ the result of $(p-1)! + 1$ is prime, while for larger $p$, it isn't.

Comment: I think the exercise is probably looking for an easier proof to this specific theorem since we have not discussed any modular arithmetics yet..

Comment: @Jemlin95 I don't think there is an easier proof for this, we just need what is shown in the duplicate.