# A Proof of Wilson’s Theorem (Without Using Modular Arithmetic)

Tags: prime-numbers, factorial

Wilson’s Theorem says that any number $n$ is a prime number if, and only if, $(n−1)!+1$ is divisible by $n$. I came across this theorem and a proof for it in some obscure math textbook that I borrowed from a friend. The thing is, school’s closed for the summer and I have no way of getting that book from him anytime soon. I remember the proof being really easy to follow, and it made no use of modular arithmetic at all. Naturally, I’ve forgotten the proof and I can’t seem to find it anywhere. I can’t seem to prove it myself either. Anyway, the only observation I’ve made so far is that $\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}$ can equivalently be written as $[(1-\frac{1}{n})(n-2)!]+\frac{1}{n}$. I’m not even sure if this is of any help, but it’s as far as I’ve gotten. I’m beginning to think that the proof I’m looking for doesn’t even exist. I’d appreciate it if someone pointed me in the right direction, or gave the entire proof.

Comment: There is no shortage of proofs online.  [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson%27s_Theorem) for instance.  Or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658294/elementary-proof-of-wilsons-theorem) on this site.  Hard to believe that you require something different from all of those.

Comment: The one where the elements are paired up uses modular arithmetic and the other one seems even tougher to wrap my head around.

Comment: @lulu I think the OP is still not familiar with "mod $p$" and hence find the proofs hard to read. In fact in the "paired up" proof one doesn't have to use "mod $p$" and can just use divisibility.

Comment: Like @WhatsUp said, I barely know what “mod p” or “mod a” or whatever means. Like you said, it’s entirely possible that the proof I’m looking for doesn’t exist at all, but I was hoping someone here would provide some insight into the theorem that might help me understand it better. Thanks for the reference, I’ll go over it, and try my best to understand it.

Comment: Note:  one direction certainly is elementary.  If $n$ is composite then $n=a\times b$.  If we can choose $a,b$ with $1<a<b<n$ then $a\times b=n$ appears in $(n-1)!$ so we are done.  If $n=p^2$ for some prime $p$ then note that, for $p>2$, $p$ and $2p$ are both $<n$ so $2p^2$ is a factor of $(n-1)!$.  Thus you only have to consider the special case $n=4$.  It's the other direction that needs work.

Comment: The basic theory of congruences is far more important that Wilson's theorem, and you can learn it quickly.  Sure, one can rewrite all those arguments without using this or that notation, but why?  You can learn all you need about the basics in a couple hours and it will come in handy for other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have been wanting to learn modular arithmetic for a while now, but I just can’t seem to find the time. It’s beyond me why I’m obsessed with Wilson’s Theorem and Wilson’s Theorem alone.

Comment: The only proof I am aware of uses group theory , not modular arithmetic , at least the direction that the congruence holds if $n$ is prime.